# How to get the selected item from a class extending ListActivity using the method onListItemClick?

Tags: android, listactivity

Here is the code of my class:

```
public class SimpleCursorAdapterConLogoActivity extends ListActivity
{

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        String categoria=getIntent().getExtras().getString("categoria");
        Cursor c = databaseHelper.getProdottiByCategoria(categoria);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        setListAdapter(new ProdottiSimpleCursorAdapter(this, c));

    }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        TextView prodotto= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prodotto);
        Cursor cursor=databaseHelper.getInfoProdotto(prodotto.getText().toString());  

        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        Intent nextScreen= new Intent(this,SchedaProdotto.class);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String name= cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("Name") );
            String price= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"));
            String link_image=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Link_image"));
            String descrizione= cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("Description") );

            nextScreen.putExtra("name",name);
            nextScreen.putExtra("price", price);
            nextScreen.putExtra("link_image", link_image);
            nextScreen.putExtra("description",description);
        }


        startActivity(nextScreen);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        databaseHelper.close();
    }

}
```

I get only the name of the TextView of the first item.
This because I use in onListItemClick method:

```
TextView prodotto= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prodotto);
```

I don't know how to get the name of the TextView related to the selected item of the list.

Comment: TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

Answer (score 0):

if you are extending a `CursorAdapter`, `l.getItemAtPosition(position)`, returns the cursor representing the row you clicked

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position)
    Intent nextScreen= new Intent(this,SchedaProdotto.class);
    String name= cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("Name") );
    String price= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"));
    String link_image=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Link_image"));
    String descrizione= cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("Description") );

    nextScreen.putExtra("name",name);
    nextScreen.putExtra("price", price);
    nextScreen.putExtra("link_image", link_image);
    nextScreen.putExtra("description",description);
    startActivity(nextScreen);
}
```

should do it